# bc (standard_in) 11: syntax error

Tags: bc

```
k=0;
for(i=432;i<500;i++){r=1;for(j=1;j<(1000-i);j++){if(j==i) m=r; r=r*j;} k=k+m*r;}
```

I ran this code in bc,but syntax error. Where the error I can't detect. Plz help.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my shell is bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing after the second last closing brace:

```
for(i=432;i<500;i++){r=1;for(j=1;j<(1000-i);j++){if(j==i) m=r; r=r*j;}; k=k+m*r;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write each statement in newline. This works in my system.

```
k=0;
for(i=432;i<500;i++)
{
  r=1;
  for(j=1;j<(1000-i);j++)
  {
    if(j==i)
       m=r;
    r=r*j;
  }
  k=k+m*r;
}
```